# How do i add <br> after the data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('body').append('<div id="berichten"; style="position:fixed; top:163px; border: 1px solid gray; background: transparant; z-index: 1000000;"></div>)');
$.get('/events', function(data) { 
    var berichten = "";
    $(data).find('.eventtitle.notread').each(function() {
        berichten += $(this).html();
        $('#berichten').html(berichten);
    });
});
```

It gives back te following results

> text1 text2 text3

etc. I want it to look like

> tekst1
>   tekst2
>   tekst3

I have tried `.add()` but i cannot get it to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
berichten += $(this).html();
```

with:

```
berichten += $(this).html() + "<br>";
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this would produce text1 text2 text3<br>.  He needs to parse the string first, and add a <br> to each element of the parsed string.

Comment: @Scottie: It's in `.each()` loop, so it should output text1<br> text2<br> text3<br>

Answer (score 2):

replace:

```
$(data).find('.eventtitle.notread').each(function() {
   berichten += $(this).html();
   $('#berichten').html(berichten);
});
```

with:

```
$(data).find('.eventtitle.notread').each(function() {
   berichten += $(this).html() + '<br />';
});
$('#berichten').html(berichten);
```

or:

```
$(data).find('.eventtitle.notread').each(function() {
   $('#berichten').append($(this).html() + '<br />');
});
```